# Override existing java annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am trying to create a customized Java annotation to override the default message of @SafeHtml . But failed.
Maybe my code is wrong.

```
@Documented
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@SafeHtml(message="Html coding text is not allowed")
public @interface MySafeHtml {
  @AliasFor(annotation = SafeHtml.class)
  String message() default "Html coding text is not allowed";
}
```

Comment: My purpose is to create a wrapper annotation to replace @SafeHtml.

Comment: just to be clear. You have an accompanying validator class for you own constraint?

Comment: after re-reading your question, wouldn't it be enough to just use the annotation as you would otherwise? @SafeHtml(message="Html coding text is not allowed")

Comment: There will be a problem if I want to change my error message someday in the future. I need to change all the @SafeHtml(message="Html coding text is not allowed")  annotation in my project.

Comment: most simple solution I can think of, is to define a String errorMessage with an @Value() annotation which you define in your properties-file. Then you'd have only one String to change in the future. Also, @SafeHtml is deprecated and will be removed in the future. You might want to find another annotation instead as well?